# Linear transformation for regression

Tags: linear-transformations, regression, linearization

Assuming we have some function with $y =
f(a, b, x, e)$, this relationship should be transformed into a simple linear regression function with $y = A + Bx + e$, with $A$ only depending on $a$, $B$ only depending on $b$ and $e$ the normally distributed error-term.

**Exercises**

(a) We assume that we have a data set with the variables y
and x in which y is modeled on $y = a \cdot b^x \cdot exp(e)$.
What is $X$ for the transformed (linear) model?

(b) Here we have $y = \exp(\sqrt{a} +
\log(b) \cdot \log(x) + e)$. Again we want to we fit with the
transformed data set (Y, X) a linear regression. How big is the parameter b?

**My approach:**

(a) I would use the logarithm, which results in:
$log(y) = log(a \cdot b^x \cdot \exp(e)) = \log(a) + x \cdot \log(b) + e$.

Hence x would be: $x = (log(y) - log(a) - e)/log(b)$.

(b) Similar approach: $\log(y) = (\sqrt{a} +log (b) \cdot \log (x) + e)$ and then:

$$\exp((\log(y) - \sqrt{a} - e)/\log(x)) = b$$

Is this approach correct at all?

Comment: As it says in the description: " e the normally distributed error-term."